# Deeper principles in classical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

While teaching introductory physics, my professor explained that the conservation of linear momentum, conservation of energy and conservation of angular momentum are based on deeper principles in classical mechanics ,namely, the homogeneity of empty space, homogeneity of time and  isotropy of space **respectively**.

Though I somewhat understand the individual meanings, what are the relations to these with the conservation laws?

Comment: The deep principle here is [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem).

Comment: Too many questions here, and most of them actually have answers elsewhere on the site (though not always in the form they are asked here).

Comment: A book by L.D.Landau and E.M.Lifshits, "Mechanics" (Course of Theoretical Physics, v.1) is a good source for this subject. Using the Hamiltonian formualtion of mechanics, on can derive the conservation laws.

Comment: symmetry leads to conserved quantities.

Answer (score 2):

After Newton an equivalent formulation of mechanics was found called Lagrangian mechanics. This features differential equations of the form $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{q}}=\dot{\mathbf{p}}$ where we define $\mathbf{p}:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{q}}}$. I'll give a very basic example of how symmetries are related to conservation laws. An infinitesimal transformation of the form $\delta\mathbf{q}=\epsilon\mathbf{k}$ achieves $$\delta L = \epsilon \left[\dot{\mathbf{p}}\cdot \mathbf{k}+\mathbf{p}\cdot \dot{\mathbf{k}}\right]=\epsilon\partial_t \mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{k}.$$ Thus $\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{k}$ is conserved iff $\delta L=0$, which is a symmetry condition.